# How to parse a SoapObject in android

Tags: android, web-services

I'm using webservices for an application to get the data from external servers. I'm able to connect to the server, send my SOAP request and able get the data back to my android class as SoapObject.
Here I'm having trouble parsing this SoapObject to retrieve the values (as strings) coming from the webservice.
My code is here:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        mInflater =  (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       System.out.println("Entered "+getClass().getSimpleName());
       //Calling the web service to get the documents list
       callService("getDocumentsList","http://wservice.friedmaggy.com/getDocumentsList");
```

-- I have created callService method to call the webservice.:

```
public void callService(String operation, String soapaction)
    {
        try {
            String SOAP_ACTION = soapaction;
            String OPERATION_NAME = operation;
            String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE =   getString(R.string.targetNamespace);
            String SOAP_ADDRESS = getString(R.string.soapAddress);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                    WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
             System.out.println("SOAP_ACTION "+SOAP_ACTION);
             System.out.println("OPERATION_NAME "+OPERATION_NAME);
             System.out.println("WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE "+WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE);
             System.out.println("SOAP_ADDRESS "+SOAP_ADDRESS);
            // System.out.println("SOAP_ACTION "+SOAP_ACTION);

            PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();

             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

             HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    SOAP_ADDRESS);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


            if(response.getPropertyCount()>0){
                data=new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                Course c = new Course((SoapObject) response.getProperty(i));

                courseList.add(c);

            }

   for (Course c : courseList) {

                data.append("CourseName :" + c.getName());

                results.add(c.getName());
            }
```

-- As seen above, i'm passing the whole response object to another bean class to fetch the values.(Course c = new Course((SoapObject) response.getProperty(i));)

Can you help me how to parse this response object to fetch the required String values out.?

Answer (score 0):

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Object response = envelope.getResponse();

Vector<SoapObject> res= null;

if (response instanceof SoapObject) {
         res = new Vector();
     res.add((SoapObject) response);
     } else if (response instanceof Vector) {
             res = (Vector<SoapObject>) response;
         }

 for(SoapObject so1: res){
             //retrieve String here from soap object using this
                     so1.getProperty(0).toString(); 
    //then so1.getProperty(1).toString and likewise      
         }
```

Comment: Hope this will help for you!!